# O que é optimistic locking field do JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistência, eclipse-link

Oque é e para que serve o "Optimistic Locking Field" do JPA? 
Observei que existe esta opção para o Eclipse Link e para o Hibernate e esta função é habilitada ao anotar um atributo versão dentro de uma classe de entidade, porém não entendi qual a sua finalidade, quando devo utilizar e quais as suas vantagens.

**Exemplo de classe anotada com o @version**

```
@Entity
public class Inventory {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ITEM_SKU", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    protected long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ITEM_SKU")
    protected Item item;
    ...
    @Version
    protected int version;
    ...
    public void setItem(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
        this.id = item.getSKU();
    }
}
```

[Documentação do Eclipse Link citando está opção](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/JSF_Tutorial)

Comment: Este link pode te ajudar: http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/jpa-entity-versioning-version-and-optimistic-locking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O propósito do Lock é impedir o surgimento de inconsistências devido ao acesso concorrente a um recurso. Existem basicamente duas estratégias de lock: O otimista e o pessimista. O pessimista simplesmente bloqueia o acesso ao recurso até que o mesmo esteja disponível novamente. Já o otimista permite o acesso mas verifica se o item foi modificado após o seu carregamento. Como fazer isso? Através do atributo `version`. O `version` permite saber se houve alteração pois ele armazena a versão atualmente carregada do objeto. Então se eu chego e acesso o objeto que está na versão 1 no momento do acesso, mas aí quando eu vou persistí-lo vejo que ele mudou para a versão 2 eu sei que alguém mexeu então pode ser lançada a exceção avisando da inconsistência do registro. Assim não se corre o risco de alguém sobrescrever uma informação salva por outra pessoa.